# jQuery: Sticky jQuery script not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress, sticky

I'm using WordPress. I've tried two sticky jQuery based scripts, both of them work when the width is more than 800px. They don't when the width is less than 800px. What could be causing the jQuery scripts to not execute when <800px?

Comment: Nobody can help you without some code to look at.

Comment: That's the problem. There is no code which limits the sticky jQuery scripts to work on desktop only. In fact I don't know how to even do that. If I did I'd enable it. Even the smooth scroll doesn't work on mobile.